# Paper Selection

Tags: paper

I’m planning on creating cards - I have plenty of PNG’s saved on my desktop and I want to print them off and than use them to create cards - I have card stock for the base of my cards, what I’m wondering is what type of paper should I print on to use to attach to my card bases. I want what I print out to be able to standup solid for the fronts of my cards and some will be used for 3D applications.
Thank you and have a great day

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to print directly on the cardstock? Or do you need the printed paper to be separate from the cardstock in some areas? Please [edit] your question or add a comment to give some more details.

Comment: I need the printed paper to be separate from the card stock

Comment: Can you tell us *why* they should be separate? And what are those "3D applications"? Are you talking about using them for boardgames, perchance?

Comment: Maybe you could link to a website that shows how these cars are supposed to look or you could add a photo of a prototype to your question? We can only give you advice if we understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This also depends on what your printer can handle - not all models can deal with thick or sturdy paper. Which kind of clashes with the “stand up solid” requirement. It would really be good if you could explain more about what exactly you want to do, if only to avoid an X-Y-problem, or in other words, it might be that your plan needs tweaking, not just the right paper.